# Sort by time data in table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

My site is based on cell phone rentals. The user can go to the site and see available devices.
I made the display of devices as a table and components from "@mui/material".

One of the columns in this table is called "last activity" (that is, since when the device is not used. Yes, this parameter is more for admin, but that is not the point). I would like to do sorting on this column.

The device data is stored in firestore. And accordingly from there I unload them for display for the user (or admin). By default, the closer the last activity to the current time, the higher the device is displayed in the table.

And then I pass this component to another component, which is responsible for building the entire table

```
 export default function DevicesTable() {
   
    const devices = useDevices(database, firestore, urlParams, hiddenItems, filters)

    return (
        <TableContainer >
            <Table >
                <DevicesTableHeader />
                <TableBody>
                    {devices.map((device) =>
                        <DevicesTableCell device={device} key={device.description.id} />)}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    );
}
```

Please tell me how I can sort by the last activity column. If you need any additional code let me know

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can query your firestore db to get the devices in the order you prefer but if you need to sort it by code you can do something like this

```
export default function DevicesTable() {
    const { database, firestore, filters } = useContext(AppContext)
    const { hiddenItems, urlParams } = useContext(PageContext)
    const devices = useDevices(database, firestore, urlParams, hiddenItems, filters)
                    .slice() // this just create a new array to order
                    .sort((a, b) => a.lastPacketTimestamp - b.lastPacketTimestamp)

    return (
        <TableContainer style={styles.TableContainerGridStyle}>
            <Table style={styles.TableStyle}>
                <DevicesTableHeader />
                <TableBody>
                    {devices.map((device) =>
                        <DevicesTableCell device={device} key={device.description.id} />)}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to my question. Yes, it works. But how can I do a full sort? So that the user, by clicking on the button, could choose on his own, in what sequence it is better for him to sort the given

Comment: @Paul sorry I didn't read your comment. I'm a bit confuse what button you are talking about?